# Argument of '#selector' does not refer

Tags: swift3, selector

Anyone can help me?

This is my code:

```
fileprivate func datapicker(sender : UITextField){

    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

    sender.inputView = datePickerView

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(sender: datePickerView, myText: sender)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

}

@objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker , myText : UITextField) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium

    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none

    myText.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}

@IBAction func fromdateAction(_ sender: UITextField) {
    datapicker(sender: sender)

}
```

Comment: When will your `datapicker` method be called? Is it when the textfield starts editing?

Comment: yes bro. it error with this line of this :
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(sender: datePickerView, myText: sender)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors can't be called like that. *You* don't get to pass the arguments for a selector, the *API* does.

You have to pass in:

```
#selector(datePickerValueChanged)
```

This means that your `datePickerValueChanged` method can't take 2 arguments, because the API expects only one.

This means that you need a way to know which text field's date picker changed. One simple way to do this is to create a property called `focusedTextField`:

```
var focusedTextField: UITextField!
```

Set this to `sender` in your `dataPicker` method:

```
focusedTextField = sender
```

And set it to nil when the user ends editing

```
// in another method that is called when the text field ends editing
focusedTextField = nil
```

Now, you can remove the second argument from `datePickerValueChanged` and use `focusedTextField` instead.

Comment: @MrIce if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark!